# Are these proofs valid? Which method of proof is better?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that S ∪ (T ∩ V) = (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V)

Here's 2 methods of proof, the first one I thought up, the second is from my notes:

First method:

a. S ∪ (T ∩ V) ⊆ (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V)

x ∈ S ∪ (T ∩ V) => x ∈ S or (x ∈ T and x ∈ V) => (x ∈ S or x ∈ T) and (x ∈ S or x ∈ V) (disjunction distributes over conjunction) => x ∈ (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V)

b. (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V) ⊆ S ∪ (T ∩ V)

x ∈ (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V) => (x ∈ S or x ∈ T) and (x ∈ S or x ∈ V) => x ∈ S or (x ∈ T and x ∈ V) (disjunction distributes over conjunction) => x ∈ S ∪ (T ∩ V)

Second method (from my notes):

a. S ∪ (T ∩ V) ⊆ (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V)

x ∈ S ∪ (T ∩ V) => x ∈ S or (x ∈ T and x ∈ V) 
1. x ∈ S => (x ∈ S or x ∈ T) and (x ∈ S or x ∈ V) => x ∈ (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V)
2. x ∈ T and x ∈ V => (x ∈ S or x ∈ T) and (x ∈ S or x ∈ V) => x ∈ (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V)

b. (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V) ⊆ S ∪ (T ∩ V)

x ∈ (S ∪ T) ∩ (S ∪ V) => (x ∈ S or x ∈ T) and (x ∈ S or x ∈ V)
1. x ∈ S => x ∈ S or (x ∈ T and x ∈ V) => x ∈ S ∪ (T ∩ V) 
2. x ∈ T and x ∈ V (if x ∉ S then ((x ∈ S or x ∈ T) and (x ∈ S or x ∈ V)) evaluates to (x ∈ T and x ∈ V)) => x ∈ S or (x ∈ T and x ∈ V) => x ∈ S ∪ (T ∩ V)

I added the words in the brackets (if x ∉ S then ((x ∈ S or x ∈ T) and (x ∈ S or x ∈ V)) evaluates to (x ∈ T and x ∈ V)) because I thought it was unclear.

Are the proofs valid? If so, which method of proof is better?

Comment: Your proof is fine, as long as the fact you stated is already established.

By the way, writing your arguments out in full detail like this is a great way to set yourself up for success in mathematics.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are correct.  Although, here is what I think you are doing in your first proof

$$\begin{align}\text{Let }x\in S\cup(T\cap V)&\iff x\in S\lor x\in(T\cap V)\\
&\iff x\in S\lor (x\in T\land x\in V)\\
&\iff x\in S\lor x\in T\land x\in S\lor x\in V\\
&\iff x\in S\cup T\land x\in S\cup V\\
&\iff x\in(S\cup T)\cap(S\cup V)\end{align}$$
This implies that $S\cup(T\cap V)=(S\cup T)\cap(S\cup V)$

Comment: Which logical principle was used in the step x∈S∨(x∈T∧x∈V)⟺x∈S∨x∈T∧x∈S∨x∈V?

Comment: Distributive property of $\lor$ in this problem.  Also, there is distributive property of $\land$.

Comment: is this proof basically the same as my proof, but more elegant?

Comment: Yes.  This is essentially your proof but instead of $\implies$ in your method, you actually have $\iff$.  So, you don't have to show $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ separately.

Comment: Althought jnh's proof is elegant.  Depending on your level of study, I feel it is an excellent habit to start with considering one direction at a time.  And then afterwards simplifying your argument.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick scan, I think both proofs are valid: you are using the (presumably) known fact that "or" distributes over "and", while the notes' proof is essentially doing that part by hand.

Note that your proofs of (a) and (b) are exact reverses of each other. In fact, each step is actually an if-and-only-if, so you could combine the two parts into a single proof with three if-and-only-ifs connecting the four equivalent statements.

Comment: So the notes' proof includes a proof of the fact that 'or' distributes over 'and'?

Comment: I believe I misunderstood. The notes proof does not actually use the distributive property, does it?

Comment: The notes proof basically proof the special case of the distributive property needed for this problem, but the method of proof is exactly the same as when proving the distributive property in general.